# Clojure compress vector

Tags: clojure

I am trying to find a Clojure-idiomatic way to "compress" a vector:

```
(shift-nils-left [:a :b :c :a nil :d nil])
;=> (true [nil nil :a :b :c :a :d])
(shift-nils-left [nil :a])
;=> (false [nil :a])
(shift-nils-left [:a nil])
;=> (true [nil :a])
(shift-nils-left [:a :b])
;=> (false [:a :b])
```

In other words, I want to move all of the `nil` values to the left end of the vector, without changing the length. The boolean indicates whether any shifting occurred. The "outside" structure can be any `seq`, but the inside result should be a vector.

I suspect that the function will involve `filter` (on the nil values) and `into` to add to a vector of `nil`s of the same length as the original, but I'm not sure how to reduce the result back to the original length. I know how to this "long-hand", but I suspect that Clojure will be able to do it in a single line.

I am toying with the idea of writing a Bejeweled player as an exercise to learn Clojure.

Thanks.

Comment: If only you allowed to shift the values to the right instead ...

Comment: The data structure I have in mind is a vector or 8 vectors. Each inner vector represents a column of jewels. The `apply-move` function will replace the jewels that disappear with `nil` values. I will then use the "compress" function to move the `nil` values to the top and then refill with jewels (I already have a function to do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
(ns ...
  (:require [clojure.contrib.seq-utils :as seq-utils]))

(defn compress-vec
  "Returns a list containing a boolean value indicating whether the
  vector was changed, and a vector with all the nils in the given
  vector shifted to the beginning."
  ([v]
     (let [shifted (vec (apply concat (seq-utils/separate nil? v)))]
       (list (not= v shifted)
             shifted))))
```

Edit: so, the same as what Thomas beat me to posting, but I wouldn't use flatten just in case you end up using some sort of seqable object to represent the jewels.

Comment: I am thinking of using a vector of vectors for the board. Each inner vector will represent a column (so that the jewels can fall). I will replace removed jewels with nils and then use the shift-nils-left function to "percolate" them to the top of the column. I'll then replace each nil with a new random jewel. The jewels themselves will probably just be :red, :white, etc. keywords.

Comment: BTW, I should have known that someone in the Clojure community would have thought of the partition problem before me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this way:

```
(defn shift-nils-left
   "separate nil values" 
    [s] 
    (let [s1 (vec (flatten (clojure.contrib.seq/separate nil? s)))] 
        (list (not (= s s1)) s1)))
```

Comment: I should have used 'not=', as dreish does. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A little more low-level approach. It traverses the input seq just once as well as the vector of non-nils once. The two more highlevel approaches traverse the input sequence two times (for `nil?` and `(complenent nil?)`). The `not=` traverses the input a third time in the worst-case of no shift.

```
(defn compress-vec
  [v]
  (let [[shift? nils non-nils]
        (reduce (fn [[shift? nils non-nils] x]
                  (if (nil? x)
                    [(pos? (count non-nils)) (conj nils nil) non-nils]
                    [shift? nils (conj non-nils x)]))
                [false [] []] v)]
    [shift? (into nils non-nils)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(def v [1 2 nil 4 5 nil 7 8] )

(apply vector (take 8 (concat (filter identity v) (repeat nil))))
```

This creates a sequence of the non- nil values in the vector using `filter` and then appends nils to the end of the sequence.  This gives the values you want as a sequence and then converts them into a vector.  The `take 8` ensures that the vector is right size.